# Implementing an efficient binary search in Erlang

Tags: erlang, binary-search

P.S. this is my first entry to SO, if I'm doing anything wrong please let me know and I'll try to fix it. I've spent pretty much all day trying to fix this algorithm implementation, and I'm at my wit's end!

A class I am currently taking is asking for 3 implementations of the same binary search algorithm in 3 substantially different languages. For one of them, I decided to go the hard way and take a shot at Erlang. Here is my code:

```
-export(main/1).

main(_) ->
    io:format("Running trials... ~n", []),
    N = [2 bsl (2 * X + 6) || X <- lists:seq(0, 7)],
    lists:foreach(fun(X) -> io:format("~p: ~p ~n", [X, time_search(X)]) end, N).

time_search(Size) ->
    A = list_to_tuple(create_list(Size)),
    Iterations = 2000000,
    time_search(A, Size + 1, 0, Iterations) / Iterations.

time_search(_, _, Sum, 0) -> Sum;
time_search(A, Key, Sum, IterationNum) ->
    Before = now(),
    bin_search(A, Key),
    time_search(A, Key, Sum + timer:now_diff(now(), Before), IterationNum - 1).

create_list(Size) -> lists:seq(1, Size).

bin_search(A, Key) -> bin_search(A, Key, 1, tuple_size(A)).

bin_search(_, _, Lower, Upper) when Lower > Upper -> false;
bin_search(A, Key, Lower, Upper) ->
    Mid = (Upper + Lower) div 2,
    Item = element(Mid, A),
    if
        Key > Item -> bin_search(A, Key, Mid + 1, Upper);
        Key < Item -> bin_search(A, Key, Lower, Mid - 1);
        true -> true
    end.
```

So this is the output:

```
128: 250.8094435 µs
512: 308.7264845 µs
2048: 368.5770285 µs
8192: 425.748134 µs
32768: 477.6267655 µs
131072: 533.340876 µs
524288: 601.023178 µs
2097152: 661.099404 µs
```

But when compared to my ruby implementation, it is is clearly orders of magnitude off from O(lg n)

EDIT: Ok, so maybe not orders...it is pretty logarithmic it seems, but it still seems wrong...

Ruby:

```
128: 10.4756 µs
512: 11.8172 µs
2048: 13.5328 µs
8192: 15.3139 µs
32768: 17.0915 µs
131072: 18.8721 µs
524288: 21.5237 µs
2097152: 21.7187 µs
```

Previously I was using Lists, but I learned that those don't have O(1) retrieval time, so I switched to Tuples. What is causing my Erlang to run so inefficiently?

Just in case, here is my Ruby implementation

```
def p5_BinarySearch
  n = Array.new(8){ |i| 2 << (2 * i + 6) }
  n.each { |x|
    time = timeSearch x
    puts "#{x}: #{time.round 4} µs"
  }
end

def timeSearch(size)
  values = createArray size
  iterations = 2e7.to_int
  totalTime = 0
  iterations.times{
    before = Time.now
    binarySearch(values, size + 1)
    totalTime += Time.now - before
  }
  totalTime * 1e7 / iterations
end

def createArray(size)
  (1..size).to_a
end

def binarySearch(values, key, low = 0, high = values.length - 1)
  return false if low > high
  mid = (low + high) / 2
  return binarySearch(values, key, mid + 1, high) if key > values[mid]
  return binarySearch(values, key, low, mid - 1) if key < values[mid]
  true
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "Running trials..."
  p5_BinarySearch
end
```

Comment: how are you running the erlang test? as an escript?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using escript <filename> in the command line to run it.

Comment: Escript interprets the code. Save the code in a `.erl` file, compile it and run it from the shell. Don't forget to add a module declaration though. Export is better as `-export([main/1]).`. The `.erl` file must have the same name as the module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Algorithm looks good but using escript interpreter is the problem in this case. 
Use escript -c  to run the escript so that the script is compiled before running rather than interpreted or you can create an Erlang module as suggested by rvirding. With  this you can see that it executes really fast.

Also better to use os:timestamp() rather than using [now()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0) to get the accurate timing values. Even better for accuracy is to use the timer:tc function.

```
{Time,_} = timer:tc(fun bin_search/2, [A, Key]),
time_search(A, Key, Sum + Time, IterationNum - 1).
```

The results were something like this on my machine. (without -c was taking around 450 microsec)

```
128: 1.105
512: 1.2005
2048: 1.4015
8192: 1.5145
32768: 1.7225
131072: 1.8515
524288: 2.024
2097152: 2.188
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and compiled it, and I am getting very similar results. Thanks! Looks like it's ~50x quicker in Erlang than Ruby! and yeah, now()'s resolution was much too small to record the time difference of every call to bin_search/2. Before I saw your suggestion to use timer:tc, I moved the timing from each individual call out to the entire 2million calls (i.e., into time_search/1). Which of course skewed the results w/ an overhead. So thanks again.